# Implement truthiness in Ruby class

Tags: ruby, boolean

Is it possible for a Ruby class to implement a truthiness method or are all objects beside false and nil automatically true by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your second question is: yes, everything else than `false` and `nil` is considered "truthy" in Ruby.

So, for example

```
a = 'foo' if 0
# => "foo"
a = 'foo' if []
# => "foo"
a = 'foo' if ''
# => "foo"
a = 'foo' if nil
# => nil
a = 'foo' if false
# => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in 1.9.3, you can get some control over `!`:

```
$ irb
>> class C
>>   def !
>>     true
>>   end
>> end
=> nil
>> c = C.new
=> #<C:0x7b5b9cd6>
>> !c
=> true
>> !!c
=> false
>>
```

Comment: You can do this, but it's not a good idea. Nobody wants to read code like this: `puts 'eh?' if c && !c`

Comment: I don't think hacking truthiness is a good idea at all; I was just offering options.

Answer (score 0):

Everything except `false` and `nil` (including 0, which sometimes confuses people coming from other languages) is truthy.