# Ruby writing type checker for booleans

Tags: ruby, class, null, boolean

I'm working on this exercise on Codewars (https://www.codewars.com/kata/typer-dot-js/), and I'm having trouble writing a type checker for booleans.

Based on my understanding, booleans either return true or false. But I've also read a lot of people saying that every object in Ruby is a boolean except for nil. I tried writing the method in a bunch of different ways, but I'm just not getting it. Below are some of the tries.

```
class Typer

def self.is_boolean? input
  input == true || false
end

def self.is_boolean? input
  input.class == TrueClass || FalseClass
end

def self.is_boolean? input
  input == nil ? false : true
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement truthiness in Ruby class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973771/implement-truthiness-in-ruby-class)

Comment: Everything in ruby is true except for nil and false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` doesn't work as you expected. For example,

```
input == true || false
```

is testing if

```
input == true
```

is truthy, or if

```
false
```

is truthy. Note that the latter isn't testing `input == false`. And that is your main misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby does not have a built-in method to convert values to Boolean. That may be by design, as the only false values in Ruby are false and nil. All other values (empty string, empty array, empty hash, 0) are true. There, however, a "hack" that can be used to convert values to Boolean: it’s called "bang-bang" or "double-bang" and it consists of two Boolean negation operators, like this:

```
!!nil
=> false

!!false
=> false

!!""
=> true

!!0
=> true

!![]
=> true

!!{}
=> true
```